# When using inside a for-loop, is there any exception or even extreme corner case that postincrement is actually better than preincrement?

Tags: c++, iterator, history, conventions

Consider the following statements:

```
for (Container<Object>::Iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
    *loop_content*
}
```

vs.

```
for (Container<Object>::Iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it) {
    *loop_content*
}
```

From my understanding, regardless what *loop_content* is, when used inside a for-loop like the example above, the preincrement version is guaranteed to be *not worse* than the postincrement version. Is there any exception or even extreme corner case that make this statement no longer true and make postincrement is actually *better* than preincrement?

If not so, here is my <s>slightly off-topic</s> second question which I have been wondering for years: Why a lot text books are teaching people to use for-loop with example like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
```

not

```
for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i)
```

My guess is that there are some medieval languages only have i++ but not ++i implemented so that people who used to these languages stay with the way they increment iterators, but I really want to know where this convention come from.

Comment: Are we allowed to write a new `Container` class?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as that part isn't executed until the loop body has run anyway. Both are equal, it's more a matter of style.

Comment: @Beta You could give example using customised iterator class as long as it is a reasonable implementation.

Comment: Like I commented on my own answer, before you worry about performance and optimizations, you should measure that this really is a bottleneck. With modern compilers it will probably be moot anyway since it most likely will be optimized anyway by the compiler.

Comment: "Why a lot text books are teaching people to use for-loop with ... i++" -- because it's traditional, it's what K&R uses, the UNIX kernel and utility software is full of such code. "My guess is ..." wrong.

Comment: @JimBalter So the question now become why K&R use i++, if ++i is regardlessly better?

Comment: It isn't better; they are exactly the same (in C; in C++ they can be different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually post-increment and pre-increment differ in only two respects: they return a different value, and post-increment is slightly more expensive because it requires making a copy of the variable. The return value is not used in a `for` loop, so if we want post- to be better than pre-, we must invent a new `Container` class whose `Iterator` has a weird and costly pre-increment operator. Something like

```
operator++()
{
  ptr = ptr->next;
  // perform some undefined behavior, or just hash the Beijing telephone book
  return *this;
}
```

This can be done as a result of simple incompetence. As for a *real* reason to put something bad in `operator++()`, I'm stumped.

P.S. I had a subordinate once who insisted that post-increment was correct, and that using pre-increment in the `for` loop would give different (wrong) results. Repeatedly correcting him didn't help; the fact that he could have *tested* this hypothesis very easily made no difference. He had somehow worked as a software engineer for over ten years without getting good at it.

Comment: So unless someone is incompetent and implements iterator plainly wrong, there is no rational reason (or benefit without considering its trade-off) for a pre-increment being more expensive than a post-increment?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason, no. As for your second question, about why so many texts use `i++`, I think it's just an old bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment, a `for` loop like

```
for (pre; cond; post) body
```

is equivalent to the following `while` loop

```
{
    pre

    while (cond)
    {
        body
        post
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `post` part, while inside the `while` loop body, is separate from the `for` loop body.

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question? So the `post` part is separate, how does that tell us whether one form of `post` might be faster or not?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It doesn't, it just elaborates on my comment to the question to make sure the OP understand that the post expression and the loop body are independent. If performance is so important, it should be profiled, but I doubt the post or pre increment will play a big part, especially since the modern compilers most likely will optimize it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's exactly how for-loop works, but my question is more about using iterator preincrement vs. postincrement at the post(afterthought) part.